# Why there is need to use html in enterprise application?

Tags: html, enterprise

I have found this question in my University Past paper.
I know what is enterprise application and i also have a detail knowledge of HTML.. But i could not understand what is the specific purpose of html in enterprise application development. I search this question in different ways from google but no site explain it in any way except the one which is (https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20160825012934AAuuG4g)
This site says (If the application is web based, it needs HTML to display its GUI.)
GUI can alse be displayed using JAVA.
I want someone explain me in a better way

Comment: Web based applications and client side applications are simple alternate approaches. There is no "better" or "required", simply different choices.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Java API also for Web Based Enterprise, Its upto you which domain is used for creating Enterprise application..

Comment: No you can use other than HTML for GUI in enterprise application, But if you choose HTML then it will be the GUI for enterprise application.

Answer (score 0):

An enterprise application can consist of anything. It's a big business application. The technology used for it can differ wildly, as you pointed out, Java can be used to display the GUI.

Most businesses opt for web-based applications utilizing HTML5 and Bootstrap. It makes mobility less of an issue when someone is out in the field (if that is one of the requirements) and easily maintainable etc.

Or you can have a windows application as your enterprise application, using .NET, Java, whatever to display an interact with your desktop. This means people have to be AT work to DO work because the application is installed on a PC, not compatible with Linux etc.

It's all about what the business needs are. HTML is just a technology that CAN be applied to an enterprise application

Comment: Thanx i understand your Answer.. One Question in mind is that HTML is not for GUI, CSS can be used for GUI.. but (https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20160825012934AAuuG4g) This site says (If the application is web based, it needs HTML to display its GUI.)

Comment: HTML is used for GUI. CSS transforms HTML. Lets boil it down to you as a person. You have 2 legs, 2 arms etc. That's the framework and what HTML defined. What colour T-Shirt you wear, is what CSS defines. They work together. One can't exist without the other. So HTML AND CSS = GUI

Comment: Also, anything web-based will output HTML. If a Java Object is used to have you type in and submit information, for example, then HTML is used to define the object so that it can load the Java file to be able to render in your browser. Nothing web-based ever happens without HTML.

Comment: Here is a page that explains embedding objects in html. this can be Flash (which can also be used for the GUI) or Java or anything you can think of, however the base is always HTML when it comes to web-based: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_object.asp

Comment: The definition of HTML: Hypertext Markup Language, a standardized system for tagging text files to achieve font, colour, graphic, and hyperlink effects on World Wide Web pages. Notice how it says "colour, graphic". That means GUI. Graphical User Interface. If a technology can output a graphic you can interact with, it's a GUI. HTML does exactly that. CSS just enhances what you can achieve in browser.

Comment: Yes i understand your answer and know i have a good understanding of GUI. Thanx a lot..

Comment: @UmairMahmood No problem. Feel free to upvote or mark as the answer if you're happy with my explanation